# R: Interpreting the emmeans' t-tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, lme4-nlme, post-hoc

Since the df are different between t-tests and emmeans ones (cf. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/369671/217618), how then should I interpreted the results?

Comment: I consider this a re-posting of @Joshua's earlier question, so I added more detail to the linked answer and request that this question be removed.

Comment: Hi rvl, thanks for your prompt and comprehensive reply. Let’s assume that the `mod1` fits adequately (or better than `mod2` ) but if I need to see only the effect of `condition` within a subset `type A` or the main effect of `condition` over the two `types`, should I do then different models? Thanks

Comment: I’d use mod1 in that case

Comment: Alright,  it makes sense to me. Thanks